# Uncaught Invariant Violation on rendering search data

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, reactjs, rendering

I am trying to implement search using React. I have 2 problems on my logic flow:

- To set input as Params
- To render the data I get from server

While I'm playing with it, I have encountered the error message

> Uncaught Invariant Violation input is a void element tag and must not
>   have `children` or use `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

And this is my code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Home.scss';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

var GetTech = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(item) {
      var csd = new AWS.CloudSearchDomain({
        endpoint: 'mycloudsearch.amazonaws.com',
        region: 'us-east-1'
      });
      var params = {
        query: {this.state.text}
      }
      csd.search(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      });
    }
    return (
      {this.props.items.map(crateItem)}
    )
  }
});

var FilteredTechs = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      text: '',
      items: []
    };
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  },
  handleSearch: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      items: this.props.items,
      text: ''
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input type="button">Search</input>
        </form>
        <GetTech items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


function Home({ techs }) {
  <FilteredTechs />
}

Home.propTypes = {
  techs: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  })).isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(Home, s);
```

I am new to React. Please advise me as you wish and your tips and comments are very appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15):

The error is pretty clear: `input`s must be void elements; that is, they must be self-closing.

This syntax is invalid: `<input type="button">Search</input>`

You want either: `<input type="button" value="Search" />`

Or: `<button>Search</button>`

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of changing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Input is self-closing tag, However there some cases in which you can use `<Input></Input>` 
You can install reactstrap package then import and use `<Input></Input>` tag instead of using `<input></input>`.
Also, you can check the link: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/input-group/
Also, you can check this for the type of input: [reactstrap Forms](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form)

Comment: Also, you can check this for the type of input: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/